# What is Clipping mask?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, clipping-mask

I am really new to Illustrator. I was going throught Qs and As on this site when i came across "clipping mask". Please what tool is that and how do i use it?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. There's an Adobe help page on the subject here: https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/clipping-masks.html

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Photoshop’s layer mask feature, a clipping mask allows you to apply a mask to multiple layers at once. By default, the bottom layer sets the boundaries for the overall group. Depending on your base layer’s content, the above layers will be affected in certain ways. Below, we’ve outlined how to use clipping masks successfully in Photoshop, so that you can come up with more creative layering in your photography and design work.

https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQXE2i12QJsniaNaDhi6YeaVp-OD5D6G8xdEwXeYJWyIV5gO-NtpA

https://pro-cdn.pixelmator.com/tutorials/guides/how-to-use-layer-masks-and-clipping-masks/layer-masks_9@2x.jpg

[image]

Comment: You can apply a mask onto multiple layers at once too. The difference of the clipping mask is that it really clips, unlike a mask.

Answer (score 0):

A clipping mask is a mask that clips. So what is clipping?

Clipping is a printing/rendering feature that stops the rasterization at the clip boundary. This means no interpolation just plain drop everything outside the area. There is really no super big distinction on a RGB screen device form any other mask, other than it having a hotkey in illustrator.

It does, however, make a difference in print for certain things in a way thats not possible on any other way. But this is really super technical and not interesting to general audience.